# How to install v8-profiler on Windows 8 (64 bit) using npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

v8-profiler is the 'standard' for tracking down memory leaks on node.js applications.

When I try to install it using `npm install v8-profiler` I get an error message that seems to complain about 32bit vs 64bit compilation.

```
C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch>npm install v8-profiler
npm WARN package.json norch@0.2.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json search-index@0.2.8 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler

> v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 install C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules
\v8-profiler
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler>node "C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\
node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  profile_node.cc
  heap_profiler.cc
  cpu_profiler.cc
  graph_edge.cc
  snapshot.cc
  graph_node.cc
..\graph_node.cc(76): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to
 'uint32_t', possible loss of data [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_
modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
..\graph_node.cc(84): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to
 'uint32_t', possible loss of data [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_
modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
..\graph_node.cc(99): error C2039: 'GetRetainersCount' : is not a member of 'v8
::HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profile
r\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(24
  9) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
..\graph_node.cc(132): error C2039: 'GetRetainedSize' : is not a member of 'v8:
:HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler
\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(24
  9) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
..\graph_node.cc(154): error C2039: 'GetRetainer' : is not a member of 'v8::Hea
pGraphNode' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler\bui
ld\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(24
  9) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
..\graph_node.cc(162): error C2039: 'GetDominatorNode' : is not a member of 'v8
::HeapGraphNode' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profile
r\build\profiler.vcxproj]
          C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8-profiler.h(24
  9) : see declaration of 'v8::HeapGraphNode'
  profiler.cc
C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506:
no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8:
:Handle<T>)' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler\bu
ild\profiler.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (..\cpu_profiler.cc)
C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506:
no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8:
:Handle<T>)' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler\bu
ild\profiler.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (..\heap_profiler.cc)
  profile.cc
..\snapshot.cc(90): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'uint64_t' to '
v8::SnapshotObjectId', possible loss of data [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\n
orch\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8.h(184): warning C4506:
no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8:
:Handle<T>)' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler\bu
ild\profiler.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (..\snapshot.cc)
C:\Users\fmcdowall\.node-gyp\0.10.15\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506:
no definition for inline function 'v8::Persistent<T> v8::Persistent<T>::New(v8:
:Handle<T>)' [C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler\bu
ild\profiler.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (..\profiler.cc)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\fmcdowall\Desktop\node\norch\node_modules\v8-profiler
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can the v8-profiler module be installed on windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was not about x64. The reason is that the plugin was designed for old Node (like 0.3)
It breaks with 0.10. You need to look at forks of the module to see fixes.
This one seems to be the most correct and supported by node inspector guys

https://github.com/nodefly/nodefly-v8-profiler

I've tried this one with removed heap profiler, which is actually broken

```
npm install git://github.com/tonistiigi/v8-profiler.git#remove-heap-profiler
```